# blackberry webworks and php

Tags: php, html, blackberry, blackberry-webworks

Hey I was wondering if it's possible to use PHP in a webworks application?

That is, I'm trying to pass information from an HTML form into a php page to be used on a server. Is that possible?

Thanks!

Comment: See http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/How-to-work-Blackberry-Java-or-Webworks-with-PHP/m-p/1432551#M183212

Answer (score 1):

php is a server side technology. Webworks requires client side technologies such as HTML5 and javascript

Comment: Hmm, yeah that's what I thought; is there anyway to link the two, that's perhaps my question

Comment: You can use an ajax approach to communicate with a php script, but that php script would still have to be located on a server somewhere (which would make the app require internet access)